# Google Workspace Add-On File Picker with CardsService

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am creating a Google Workspace Add-On for Google Drive where I would like to have it as a sidebar where I can select files from the folder I am running in and then upload them to an external service through an API.

All the API backend is set up but I don't know how to do this with the CardsService. I have done something similar with an Editor Add-on where I can use HTML elements to select a file but apparently, CardsService doesn't have this functionality.

I don't think that using Google Picker is a very "smart" solution because I would have to navigate to the folder and they are quite nested. Hence the add-on in a folder, to save time looking for files in folders.

Is there another way to select these files in a Workspace Add-On?

Comment: Can you detail more what the add-on would do? Couldn't you use apps script DriveApp to get the files?

Comment: I need a UI (sidebar) that the user can select a few specific files from within some folder that will be sent to an external service (uploaded somewhere)

Comment: And why not creating a multiple selection with [Class SelectionInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input) and only show the user the titles of the files you want them to see?